How to color only a piece of a bar in a bar plot
I wrote the following code:
set.seed(123)

# Create the dataframe
df_long <- data.frame(
  trait = rep(c("Trait1", "Trait2", "Trait3", "Trait4", "Trait5"), each = 2), 
  type = rep(c("eur_ita", "eur_ita_2"), times = 5),   
  value = c(runif(5, 5, 15), runif(5, 8, 20))
)

# Remove rows where eur_ita_2 is shorter than eur_ita for the same trait
df_long_filtered <- df_long %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = value) %>%  # Reshape data for comparison
  dplyr::filter(eur_ita_2 > eur_ita) %>%  # Keep rows where eur_ita_2 is greater than eur_ita
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c(eur_ita, eur_ita_2), names_to = "type", values_to = "value")  # Reshape back to long format

# Check the filtered data
print(df_long_filtered)

# Create the bar plot with the filtered data
ggplot(df_long_filtered, aes(x = trait, y = value, fill = type, alpha = type)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.6), col = "black", width = 0.6) + 
  labs(x = "Trait", y = "Percentage of r2", fill = "Type") +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c(
      "eur_ita" = "red",
      "eur_ita_2" = "black"
    )
  ) +
  scale_alpha_manual(
    values = c(
      "eur_ita" = 1,
      "eur_ita_2" = 0.9
    ),
    name = NULL  # Removes the legend title
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, size = 10),
    strip.text = element_text(size = 10),
    panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA, linewidth = 0.8),
    strip.background = element_blank()
  )

How can I modify the code so as to color only a piece on the highest bar? Especially the difference between the two column at a specific x values, as in the attached example, where I would like to color in red only the piece of difference between the two bars of the specific x value, so the upper part of the dark bar:


I don't understand why you'd want to do this, and to be perfectly honest, I think it makes for a bad chart, but it is possible:
df2 <- df_long_filtered %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = trait, names_from = type, values_from = value) %>% 
  mutate(diff = eur_ita_2 - eur_ita,
         eur_ita_2 = eur_ita) %>% 
  pivot_longer( cols = -c(trait), names_to = "type",  values_to = "value" )

ggplot()+
  aes(x = trait, y = value, fill = type) +
  geom_col(data = df2 %>% filter(type == "eur_ita"),  col = "black", width = 0.3, just = 1)+
  geom_col(data = df2 %>% filter(type != "eur_ita"), position = position_stack(), col = "black", width = 0.3, just = 0) + 
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c(
      diff = "red", 
      eur_ita = "red",
      eur_ita_2 = "black"
  )
  ) 


I second the "makes for bad chart" comment
